# Linq Select Subset of master list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a master list of complex objects.

I have a list of int ids that I need to select the corresponding complex object out of the master list.

this doesn't work

```
MasterListofComplexObj.Where(u => MasterListofComplexObj.Select(i => i.Id).Contains(ChildListofIntIds));
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or wrong results? Could you give some input values and the output you expect?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should work:

```
var results = MasterListofComplexObj.Where(u => ChildListofIntIds.Contains(u.Id));
```

Comment: you're in....thanks for the help. in my mind the logic is kind of reversed, you take the child list and see if it contains the id of you're selecting from the mast list.  thanks again

Comment: yes the syntax is not what you would intuitively expect - but since you are looking at each `ComplexObj` one by one it does make sense

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = from obj in MasterListofComplexObj
    where ChildListofIntIds.Contains(obj.Id)
    select obj;
```

This is an IEnumerable.  You may want to .FirstOrDefault() it to get one object.

Translates to 
MasterListofComplexObj.Where(item => ChildListofIntIds.Contains(item.Id))

No select necessary if you want the object itself and not one of its properties.

Answer (score 1):

The other more general thing to look into would be Join:

```
var results = MasterList.Join(ChildList, (m => m.Id), (c => c), ((m,c) => m));
```

I believe, but can't back up with citation or experimental data, that Join would be faster than the Where -> Contains piece.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work as well:

```
double[] numbers1 = { 2.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 };
double[] numbers2 = { 2.2 };

var isNumberTwoSubsetOfNumberOne = !numbers2.Except(numbers1).Any();
```